# symlink script does not exist on startx

Tags: bash, path, x11

The problem I am having is running a symbolic link called `example` inside a script (example points to b.sh).
Running `$ example` from a terminal appends the message `scriptB was found` to the log. The same happens if I run `$ ./b.sh` from `$HOME`. However, `example` is not executed while starting up X.
I have created the following minimal setup on my system to imitate my problem.

**a.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
type example ||
    echo "error: example could not be found." >>"$HOME/example.log"
~/b.sh
```

**b.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "scriptB was found" >>"$HOME/example.log"
```

**.xinitrc**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -x "$HOME/a.sh" ]; then
    bash ~/a.sh
fi
```

### The minimal setup

- X executes `a.sh`
- link created with `$ ln -s ~/a.sh ~/.local/bin/example`
- scripts made executable with `$ chmod u+x a.sh b.sh` and verified to be executable with `ls -l`
- appended `$HOME/.local/bin` to my PATH environment variable in `.bashrc`

The log after restarting X (or rebooting) is:

```
error: example could not be found.
scriptB was found
```

Comment: `>/dev/null` only redirects stdout, not stderr.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just have that there to silence a.sh. example still seems to not exist with &> redirection or no redirection.

Comment: `appended $HOME/.local/bin to my PATH environment variable` where and how exactly? It's not in `.xinitrc`?

Comment: @KamilCuk in my `.bashrc` I have `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"`

Comment: `in my .bashrc` So it's in `.bashrc`. Your script does not use `.bashrc`. Export path in your script. Note that you have `#!/bin/bash` yet you use `. ~/a.sh`, so it's using `sh`, not `bash` (and not using `.bashrc` either way anyway). And that is some very strange `bash -c '. ~/b.sh'`, just run the script `bash ~/b.sh`, sourcing in a subshell makes little sense.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ah, I forgot that bashrc is not run on startx. Exporting the local/bin inside the shell worked. Thank you!

Comment: All that sourcing `.` is strange, like `[ -x "$HOME/a.sh" ] || . ~/a.sh` - you test for executable, then if the file is __not__ executable, you source it? What if the file does not exists? I would usually see `[ -x "$HOME/a.sh" ] && ~/a.sh`  or `[ -f "$HOME/a.sh" ] && . ~/a.sh`, but anyway use `if` for readability.

Comment: And thank you for pointing out my sourcing misuse. I compiled this quickly and didn't double check. I will fix the question and re-test.

Comment: Why not replacing `type example` by `[[ -L $HOME/example ]]`? Your `type` statement would assume, that your `$HOME` is in the `PATH`, which is an unlikely scenario anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 I wanted to have the script to find `example` no matter its location. If `example` was somewhere deep, I would have to write the whole absolute path which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @minguine : In this case, you have to put the location into the `PATH`. Your failed `type` statement just says that at this point, the `PATH` is not set up correctly, which is something you can verify easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> .... ~/.local/bin/example
> ```

So add that path to `PATH`.

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
example
```

Comment: Appending `$HOME/.local/bin` to my PATH in `.xinitrc` fixed my problem